# how to check for activity or lack thereof on a unix file directory using perl or unix commands

Tags: perl, shell, unix

**Scenario:**
I have a process where many files are being copied (scp'd) to a DestinationServer by Host1, Host2, Host3, Host4 for example. Going to the same common directory: DestinationServer:/home/target. All the files are unique so no files will be overwritten. Host1-Host4 will have a cronjob that will launch their scp script to DestinationServer. The caveat is the Hosts are in different time zones, locations. So, they will finish at different times.

**Need:**
Since the files are being scp'd to Destination:/home/target, what is the best way to programmatically check when those scp's from the other Hosts are done??

**Options:**
My options are to programmatically do this either in perl or shell if possible.

What do I look for, what unix commands or perl modules could I use to help determine when the processes would finish? Any ideas, examples would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) kind of approach: copy all files to a temporary directory, then after the transfer is complete have the originating host perform a rename into the target directory via ssh. That way when a file appears in the target directory, you know that it is complete.

I suggest this because if you just scp files into the target directory and monitor the directory in whatever way, you cannot distinguish a complete transfer from an interrupted scp command or a network failure.

Answer (score 0):

[`SGI::FAM`](http://search.cpan.org/~jglick/SGI-FAM-1.002/lib/SGI/FAM.pm), [`Sys::Gamin`](http://search.cpan.org/~garnacho/Sys-Gamin-0.1/lib/Sys/Gamin.pm)

Comment: [File::ChangeNotify](http://p3rl.org/File::ChangeNotify) is the best FS watcher. -1 because using a watcher alone suffers from the problem Jouni pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Similar but alternative way to Jouni is to use semaphore files. Before scp-ing files originating host puts up semaphore-file and when finished, remove it. So you know, it's time.

Comment: Depends of your implementations and needs. You could ask from directory  (with scp, for example) "*.sem" and if you got sem-files, it is too early, files are still coming.